# По лесу - местный падеж?

Tags: морфология, падежи

Мой вопрос таков.

Какой падеж "я гуляю в лесу"? - предложный, ранее - местный, который объединён с предложным. Местный падеж указывает локацию, место

Хорошо, но что если я немного меняю форму: "я гуляю по лесу"?
семантика остаётся прежней: я указал своё местоположение
местный падеж, как следствие объединения - сегодня предложный?
но прямой вопрос "по чему" - это вроде как дательный падеж
с другой стороны, есть вариант с вопросом "где", относящий снова к предложному

какой вариант правильный? дательный (по вопросу)? предложный (по указанию локации и тоже вопросу)? и почему?

Answer (score 2):

[МЕСТНЫЙ ПАДЕЖ](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B6)

> Mecтный пaдeж xapaктepизyeтcя yпoтpeблeниeм иcключитeльнo в coчeтaнии
>   c пpeдлoгaми «нa» и «в».

То есть предлог "по" никогда не имел отношения к местному.

Все падежи с предлогом "по" - [см. с примерами](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE).

---

Ещё о местном падеже - ответ Справки Грамоты.ру:

[Вопрос № 263338](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=263338)

> Здравствуйте. Вот почему на вопрос - "где?", в словах ответах, в
>   окончании, пишется буква "е", а в некоторых, таких как, "в бору", "в
>   лесу" ставится буква "у". (где? - в Москве, в чемодане, в диване, в
>   реке и т.д.)

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Да, окончание *-е*  – типичное окончание предложного падежа для
>   существительных второго (по школьной грамматике) склонения. Однако у
>   некоторых слов (их не больше 100) в предложном падеже встречается
>   окончание *-у* (как правило, в обстоятельственном значении места, реже
>   состояния или времени действия): *в лесу, на мосту, на берегу, в носу*
>   и др. Это так называемый местный падеж (локатив) – одно из подзначений
>   предложного падежа. В изъяснительном значении предложного падежа у
>   таких слов употребляется окончание *-е,* ср.: *говорить об аэропорте*
>   (изъяснительное значение) – *находиться в аэропорту* (местное
>   значение), *вспоминать о доме – работать на дому.*

Comment: Спасибо. Но разве местный падеж характеризуется предлогом?

И вообще, складывается устойчивое ощущение, что местный падеж характеризуется даже не предлогами и окончаниями, а смыслом. "В бою" - НЕ местный падеж. А "брожу по лесу", "по опушке" - вполне определённо указывается местонахождение, равно как и "брожу в лесу", "на опушке"

Comment: За всеми падежами "закреплены" предлоги. Просто в некоторых случаях предлог может относиться к разным падежам, как в моей кликабельной ссылке на предлог "по". Нет, падеж не определяется смыслом.

Comment: Пытаюсь понять смысл падежей. Дело в том, что путаница возникла из общением с преподавателем русского языка (в оригинале было "по опушке" - он заявил, что это предложный, т.к. "место, где"). Правильно ли я понимаю, что каждое слово в определённом падеже пишется однозначно, т.е. падеж определяет его окончание? Если так, то слово "лес" в предложном падеже будет иметь окончание "е" (о лесе).

Таким образом, если кто-то решил, что "по лесу" - это предложный, т.к. вопрос "где", местонахождение и т.д., то он обязан будет написать "по лесе", и это уже очевидно, что неправильно